# Среда разработки С++ для Mac OS X

Tags: c++, ide, ос, mac

Ищу удобную и свободную среду разработки под С++ для Mac OS X. Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: @cheremushkin `Xcode`?

Comment: @Котик, да, в последних версиях они вроде реализовали кое-какую поддержку C++ (в т.ч. нового стандарта), но его поддержка там, по большей части, "для галочки" (см. Objective-C++).  
Из более продвинутых - [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) от JetBrains.

Comment: @VioLet А разве в `AppCode` поддержка `C++` тоже не "для галочки"? *(ни разу не пользовался, поэтому и не знаю :)*

Comment: @Котик, это я неправильно выразился - продвинутый не в плане поддержки C++ (я сам на нём не пишу, всё со слов знакомых), а хотя бы потому, что в AppCode субъективно удобнее навигация и  процесс рефакторинга кода - это то, что отметил лично я после двух лет в Xcode. Ну и вообще, он стоит на движке IntelliJ Idea, если не ошибаюсь - а про него мало плохого слышно.   
[Обзор AppCode](http://touchdev.ru/documents/4343).

Comment: а qt creator не подходит ?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, сидела я с XCode, мучалась, проклинала свою жизнь, пока в ней не появился APPCODE и не спас её.... Мало того что XCode глючный, так я ещё столкнулась с проблемой, что он ПОСТОЯННО падает, код слетает, который я успеваю написать, если вручную не сохранить. И даже ручное сохранение не всегда спасало. Работать с ним было просто невыносимо. И тут я узнала про AppCode - теперь сижу только на нём и горя не знаю!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Qt Creator, естественно. На данный момент это лучшая IDE для С++ под UNIX-образные платформы. И поскольку она существует для Mac OS X, то ответ очевиден.

Answer (score 0):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Answer (score 0):

C++ На столько старый язык и темболее С, что программы на них пишутся либо в Vim либо в  Emacs.

А если серьезно, то пока бесплатное [cLion](http://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) в копилку :)

Answer (score -2):

1. [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)
2. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)